# Printing in Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing

I have a Laserjet 6MP (parallel printer port only) connected via a USB to Parallel cable.  It used to work fine, until I built a new computer and moved the printer to the new PC.  Windows sees the printer, claims to load the driver (is in fact attached to USB001), and claims everything is fine.  When I print, the file gets stuck in the queue and does not print.  I've already removed the printer and drivers and re-loaded them, all to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest x64 driver from HP [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=14980&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=25477&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063). I've had limited success with the built in drivers in Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use USB 2.0 HighSpeed cable. Use USB 2.0 or 1.1 port.

28AWG -0.81 m, 26AWG -1.31 m, 24AWG -2.08 m, 22AWG -3.33 m, 20AWG -5.00 m.

[image: mark USB 2.0 cable]

[image: Use USB 2.0 HighSpeed]

[Filtering Out Interference Signals with Cable Ferrites](http://www.ce-mag.com/archive/02/11/may.html)

It so happens that lost ferrite latch. Set them closer to the edges of the cable.

[image: ferrite core]

[image: ferrite core]

[HP LaserJet, Color LaserJet, and LaserJet AiO/MFP Products - Install the driver included in the Windows 7 operating system (OS)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?&objectID=c02536257)